# Excel Range to DataTable VB.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net, multidimensional-array, datatable

My code below creates a 2D Array from an Excel Range. I then want to 'paste' that array into a DataTable. My code below seems to work fine for creating the DataTable with all the correct Columns and then creating the array from the Excel Range. I'm just having trouble adding the array to the DataTable.

Hoping someone can help me out with this.
Thanks in advance.

```
    Public Sub ExcelRangeToDataTable()

        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim WB As Excel.Workbook
        Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim DataRange As Excel.Range
        Dim LR As Integer

        xlApp = GetObject(, Constants.ExcelApp)
        WB = xlApp.Workbooks("TestWB")
        WS = WB.Sheets("Sheet1")
        LR = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, "A").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
        DataRange = WS.Range("A" & Constants.First_Row & ":Y" & LR)

        Dim DT As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Call CreateDataTable(DT) 'Create the DataTable and all Columns

        Dim excelRows As Object(,) = DataRange.Value 'Create a 2D Array

        'Add the 2D Array to the DataTable
        For i As Integer = 1 To excelRows.GetUpperBound(0)
            DT.Rows.Add()
            For j As Integer = 1 To excelRows.GetUpperBound(1)
                DT.Rows(i).Item(j) = excelRows(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: While the array returned from Excel will start at index one (1), the DataTable Rows collection index starts at zero (0) as does the Row's cell collection.  The code is attempting to map the array's indices to the collection indices, but is off by one.

Comment: Thanks @TnTinMn for bringing this to my attention. This is how I resolved the issue.
`DT.Rows(i - 1).Item(j - 1) = excelRows(i, j)`